# Error while running compare models in Pycaret 2.2 on Rapids 0.19 environment(CONDA)

Tags: rapids, pycaret

I am facing this issue for RandomForestRegressor while comparing models.My Pycaret version is Pycaret2.2 and it is running in Rapids-0.19 Environment.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgJIh.png).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you've tried and is failing so someone in the community can best assist you

Comment: I have used the regression tutorial 102 as the code from the Pycaret tutorials repo.The code description is being mentioned below which I ran.

Comment: from pycaret.regression import *

exp_reg102 = setup(data = data, target = 'target', session_id=123,normalize = True,remove_outliers=True,transformation=True, rare_level_threshold = 0.05,log_experiment = True, experiment_name = 
commons',use_gpu=True,fold_strategy='kfold')


top3 = compare_models(n_select = 3)

Answer (score 0):

In the current nightly release of pycaret, these issues no longer present with the nightly release cuML (21.06). You can install the nightlies if you would like to use these together right now.

When these libraries officially release their next stable versions, you will no longer need to use the nightly.